# Problema en dar un orden específico al agrumento fill de la opción aes de ggplot() de la libreria ggplot2 en R

Tags: r, ggplot

estoy intentando dar un orden específico a las barras de mi gráfico. Quiero que la primera barra sea "línea base" y la segunda barra, "Cantidad Impresiones y Copiado", para eso utilice el siguiente código que sí me sirvió en otro gráfico:

```
Tabla_C$Indicador = factor(Tabla_C$Indicador, levels = c ("Linea base", "Cantidad Impresiones y Copiado"))

Tabla_C |>
ggplot(aes(x = MES_CONSUMO, y=Total_P, fill=Indicador)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity")+                
  theme_minimal()+
 labs(x="", y= "Total") +  
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#1675b3", "#81e8d5"))+
 geom_text(aes(label = Total_P),
         vjust = -0.3, 
         position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

Sin embargo, las barras del gráfico aparecen en distinto orden:

[image: Grafico]

Comment: Hola Daniela bienvenida a Stackoverflow, para poder ayudarte con tu pregunta es necesario que agregues una muestra de tus datos a la publicación. Puedes agregar la salida de dput(Tabla_C). De esta manera podremos replicar tu grafico.

Comment: Daniela, no logro reproducir tu problema con datos sintéticos, en mi caso cada barra respeta el orden dado. Como te dice Rolando, sin los datos no podemos saber que ocurre.